# Why does this website cause tearing in IE?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, tearing

http://gaxweb.eu/deploy/phenix/en-de/products?target=1340

I've got a weird IE bug here that causes tearing if you scroll that carousel with your mousewheel for example. The images are being torn into 2 parts, just like tearing in 3D games when you play without vsync. How is this possible? It works fine in other browsers. And even more important: how shall I fix this?

The weirdest thing: I've used this on another website before, and there no tearing appears. I've run out of ideas, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, I can see the tearing. IE appears to be doing something internally, like deciding that it's running out of clock cycles and giving up on rendering the complete image before it continues to scroll. The carousel is much better behaved in firefox.

Answer (score 2):

I am getting a javascript error in IE which I am not getting in other browsers. Start there as it may be causing extra processing or a delay leading to the tearing.

[image: Error]

Comment: Fixed that locally, didn't help unfortunately.